# How to get the keyboard input into a string without displaying it in windows forms?

Tags: c#, forms, keyboard

In my windows form application, I want the input characters from the keyboard to be collected in a string (even if there is no active input field in the form),
I mean that if my form window is active whenever a key is pressed it should be appended to a string without having any input fields in the form, that I'm going to use the input in the background without showing it to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form constructor set KeyPreview property to true and associate event handling with the keyevent you want

```
public MyForm : base()
{
    this.KeyPreview = true;

    // handle KeyDown event
    this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(MyForm_KeyDown);
}
private void MyForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // do what you need
}
```